# Не получается создать статическую переменную в структуре

Tags: структуры, переменные, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте! Почему не получается создать такую штуку:

```
struct SMOKE{
static int index_ss;
}er[5];
```

`Direct X` и `OpenGl` не использую...
Вылетает ошибка(это линковщик ругается?):

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int SMOKE::index_ss" (?index_ss@SMOKE@@2HA)
```

Что не так?

Comment: а причем тут Direct X и OpenGl?

Comment: @Alerr, невозможно сделать статическим только одно из полей структуры. Только всю ее целиком.

    struct SMOKE {
       int index_ss;
    };
    ....
    static struct SMOKE er[5]; // статический массив из 5-ти структур

Comment: Неправда ваша. Я зык позволяет создавать статические переменные члены и для класса и для структуры. Проблема заключается только в том, что они не принадлежат своему классу (структуре), а просто находятся в его области видимости, потому и требуют отдельного создания.

Comment: Direct X.., это я в сети искал решение такой же проблемы, там что-то про Direct X говорили... говорили что все из-за него...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Видимо Вы неправильно объявляете переменную.

```
struct SMOKE{
    static int index_ss;
}er[5];
```

Но кроме этого ее необходимо еще и создать. Для этого в cpp файл добавляем строку:

```
int SMOKE::index_ss = 0;
```

После этого ошибка линковки уйдет.

Comment: Сделал int SMOKE::index_sm = 0; после всей структуры, ошибка ушла. А в чем проблема была? почему линковщик ругается?

Comment: Попробовал проинициализировать эту переменную в конструкторе структуры, та же ошибка... Можно сделать так, чтобы переменная статическая инициализировалась через сруктуру?

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что они не принадлежат своему классу (структуре), а просто находятся в его области видимости, потому и требуют отдельного определения. У Вас получилась ситуация, в которой переменная объявлена, но не определена (фактически ее еще нет, память под нее не выделена). Именно на это и ругается линковщик.
Почитайте Старуструпа, он хорошо это описывает. Если покажется тяжелым и перегруженным - могу посоветовать Уолтер Савич "C ++ во всей полноте".  Правила выделения и освобождения памяти - тема не только важная в C, но и очень интересная

Comment: Спасибо), очень помогли